# most common value in column CSV file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am beginner in python and
I need to get the most common value of that column using code

I have next table from csv file:

| elements | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | y |
| 2 | y |
| 3 | y |
| 4 | n |
| 5 | n |

How I can get most common (common means that the count of y is 3, count of n is 2 , so common is y) 'value'?

Comment: please share a bit more on what you have tried so far and where exactly you are stuck. A common approach to such tasks is to use pandas. 
[read csv with pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html), [group by value and count](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

//
placeholder for 30 characters
//

df['value'].value_counts()

Answer (score 1):

You can use `count_values()` and extract it from the result

```
df.value.value_counts(sort=True).index[0]
# 'y'
```

Just be careful what should happen if there are multiple 'most common' values.